# When i upload git it shows someone else's name

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I changed my account in Control Panel -> Windows Credentials -> git:https://github.com but when I upload my git it shows someone else's name. We wish everyone help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtNJV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK9Am.png)

Comment: Check your git config for that repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```bash
git config --global user.name "FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME"
git config --global user.email "MY_NAME@example.com"
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. 
I solved the problem thanks to your way